# Why does subprocess.run create return code 1 even if the command was successful?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, chocolatey

From within python, I am trying to check if chocolatey is installed on a windows machine. I used `subprocess.run` to implement that, however, the return code is 1 even if chocolatey is installed.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['choco'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(result.returncode)
```

Adding options won't change its result. If I test a windows command like `dir` everything works as expected. Where is my mistake here?

**Edited**:

As some comments indicated it was not clear what I meant by *options*, actually I tried similar things as it was suggested already before. However, I was mislead by two things

1. The idea that a call which I consider to be *sucessful* would alwas return 0 as code. A good explanation was given by Shine J.
2. And it turned out that I tried to provide options *inline*. Instead I had to provide it as a second argument. From the documentation of [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (which is called underneath) this became clear to me. Chocolatey also returns 0 as return code if called like this:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['choco','-v'], capture_output=True)

print(result.returncode)
```

However, I believe that Shine J is right in saying that it is better to check if the file is present. Therefore, I will accept this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: What is `choco` and why do you assume it should not return 1 ?

Comment: it returns 1 because it has successfully finished the code

Comment: Simply running `choco` may not be a valid invocation of the command. Run it yourself on the command line and see what the exit code is. Maybe something like `choco --help` will return successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on the value returned by your program with different arguments.

For example, when I run the following on my computer (git is installed):

```
result = subprocess.run(['git'], capture_output=True)
```

`result.returncode` is 1

If I run git with parameter --version like this:

```
result = subprocess.run(['git','--version'], capture_output=True)
```

`result.returncode` is 0

To really check if a program exists or not (on Windows) you could do something like:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.run(['choco'], capture_output=True)
    print(result)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Program not installed")
```

Check out this [official documentation on Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Answer (score 1):

You ran [`choco`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/) without any arguments, meaning it didn't get a command to perform. It's up to `choco` whether that's regarded as an error; I suspect it is, much like if you passed it an unknown command. You may want to pass it a command that should succeed, such as [`choco help`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/help).